# Google cloud storage MediaLink HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I've added a file to Google cloud storage
with this permission:
allAuthenticatedUsers:OWNER

and I'm giving my users the MediaLink to this file, but when they try to get via http request they get:
 HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

what do they need to do before http request to the MediaLink?

Thanks,
Snabel

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25334525/2263165.

If your users are accessing the media link via a simple HTTP GET, they are not authenticated.  Your users need to use one of the approaches described in that answer (Cookie auth or OAuth2 via the Developers Console or gsutil).

Comment: Thanks,

let me add more info, i give my users a MediaLink to some audio file, which they can download and play. so i can't ask them to authenticate.
i thought about making the files visible for all users (read permissions) but use "Whitelisting by IP Address (Server-side applications)" to block requests from the rest of the world.
but it's not working, requests from any IP address are accepted. 

i followed the steps here:
https://developers.google.com/console/help/

generated a server key with the IPs i wanted, but still didn't work...

Comment: can i use "Whitelisting by IP Address" for Google Cloud Storage JSON API?
i followed the steps here: "https://developers.google.com/console/help/" but it didn't work.
I gave the objects these permissions
AllUsers - read
i want to allow access to requests from certain IPs, so i decided to use "Whitelisting by IP Address"
but it didn't work...i took the object MediaLink, copied it to the browser and i was able to access it, even though the PC IP address was not defined in the server Key i generated.
the link i used it: object-Media-Link?key=myKey

Comment: AllUsers:Read permission is not related to IP Whitelisting, that will make the medialink accessible by anyone.  If you want to provide links to specific unauthenticated users, you could use Signed URLs: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs  While any user who has the signed URL could access it, you could limit distribution to only your users and create an expiration time.

Comment: Thanks. I'm thinking about using signed URLs, but I'm having some issues with Expiration parameter. i want to give my users links which they can use as long as they want, with no expiration date. is there a special value to this parameter which says this link never expires?

Comment: The expiration parameter is required, but you could set it to a value hundreds of years in the future.